# Scrapy building JSON dictionaries: "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "set") to str"

Tags: python, scrapy

I am performing the spider below for academic purposes on tomtom live traffic data. The data is retrieved from an underlying JSON like this one: https://api.midway.tomtom.com/ranking/live/ITA_milan

I want to crawl for several cities and create a dictionary like:

> {'Amsterdam': {'var1': value1, 'var2': value2}, 'Brussels': {'var1', value1 (...)}}

This is my spider so far which gives me

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "set") to str

What can I do to get the desired structure in the dictionary? I keep coming back to those basic questions, unfortunately. I am still learning python from scratch.
Cheers
marcello

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import json
import requests
import datetime
from scrapy.spiders import Spider

data = {}

class TomSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'tom_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['tomtom.com']
    start_urls = ['https://api.midway.tomtom.com/ranking/live/']

    def start_requests(self):
        data['city'] = {'FRA_paris', 'london-traffic', 'berlin-traffic', 'amsterdam-traffic', 'brussels-traffic',
                        'frankfurt-am-main-traffic'}
        url = 'https://api.midway.tomtom.com/ranking/live/' + data['city']
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, meta = {'item': data})

    def parse(self, response):
        jsonresponse = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        data = response.meta['item']
        data["content"] = jsonresponse["data"]

        yield data
```

Comment: `{Amsterdam, {'var1': value1, 'var2': value2}, Brussels{'var1', value1 (...)}}` is not a valid python literal.

Comment: But this is? I forgot the quotation marks. {'Amsterdam', {'var1': value1, 'var2': value2}, 'Brussels', {'var1', value1 (...)}}

Comment: Now it's an valid literal, however, it is not a `dict` but a `set`, however, it will error because `set` objects cannot contain `dict` objects because `dict` objects are not hashable.

Comment: aha! Until now I thought ```dict```and ```set``` are the same.

Comment: I think you mean `{Amsterdam: {'var1': value1, 'var2': value2}, Brussels: {'var1', value1 (...)}} ` note the colons, with just commas, it's a set literal. You seem to try to use this in your `url = ...` but not sure *what you were expecting*

Comment: So what did you expect `'https://api.midway.tomtom.com/ranking/live/' + {'FRA_paris', 'london-traffic', 'berlin-traffic', 'amsterdam-traffic', 'brussels-traffic', 'frankfurt-am-main-traffic'}` to do? That's trying to use the `+` operator on a string and set, that is not a defined operation.

Comment: I saw a similar notation somewhere else: I thought it would give me only one element of the set (one city). Then create the url and pass this to the ```parse``` function. Then do this again for the next element (city). Could I restructure this into a for-loop and run parse several times?